# How to use gettimeofday() to get the run time?

Tags: c++, c, system-calls

My question is what's the meaning of "t1.tv_usec-t0.tv_usec"? I think this part is useless, and whats the meaning of "* 1000000"?

```
gettimeofday(&t0, 0);
/* ... */
gettimeofday(&t1, 0);
long elapsed = (t1.tv_sec-t0.tv_sec)*1000000 + t1.tv_usec-t0.tv_usec;
```

Comment: What problem do you try to solve with this code? How can we know, what 1000000 means?

Comment: Regarding the multiplication, it might help if you understand that `usec` stands for *microseconds*.

Answer (score 6):

It's converting the total time to μs because `tv_usec` is the micro seconds part of the total time and `tv_sec` is the seconds part, and you need to multiply the number of seconds by `1000000` to get the number of μs they represent.

Comment: Multiply instead of divide?

Comment: Yes multiply 1 second is 1000000 micro seconds. You could divide `tv_usec` by `1000000` to get the number of seconds as a decimal value.

Comment: `tv_sec` is seconds. How will multiplying seconds by a 1000000 produce micro seconds?

Comment: @RSahu How many microsseconds is a single second?

Comment: Got it, and THX :)  btw, "t1.tv_usec-t0.tv_usec" what does this one do?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, thanks. Must be too early in the morning.

Comment: @RSahu No problem, can happen to the best of us :)

Comment: It's computing the time difference from now to when the first `gettimeofday()` call was made, thus giving you the elapsed number of microsecond.

Comment: @RSahu It happens to me very often actually. And I am almost a Physicist.